# Getting the google map in code

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I have a google map which I'm trying to use in my code. However, I get an error. After debugging I found out that my Google Map object is null.

xml:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

activity:

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

When I debug and i check 'map' it says that map is null. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are doing nothing wrong.

`getMap` can return null for many reasons. If you want to know your case, call [`isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) and compare result with status codes.